# Как не экранировать ссылки в JSON

Tags: php, json, json-encode

```
<?php
// Пришли сотни строк из некого репозитория, уже гарантировано валидные для JSON и не требующие экранирования
// Мы не можем повлиять на источник
$inputData = array(
    'https://stackoverflow.com/',
    'DN12345/2023'
);

// Нужно добавить их в ответ
$response = array(
    "version" => 1,
    "timestamp" => "1695789789",
    "data" => $inputData
);

// Ответ ожидают в формате JSON без дополнительного экранирования
// Мы не можем повлиять на потребителя
echo json_encode($response, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
```

Ожидание/результат:

```
{"version":1,"timestamp":"1695788642","data":["https://stackoverflow.com/","DN12345/2023"]}  
{"version":1,"timestamp":"1695788642","data":["https:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/","DN12345\\/2023"]}
```

Строки нужно добавить в элемент примерно такого массива, иначе просто можно было бы разделить строки запятыми, а слева и справа указать скобки без использования `json_encode`.

Comment: _Содержание вопроса зафиксировано в последнем варианте, предложенном автором вопроса._

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо добавить флаг `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`, который отключит экранирование слешей:

```
echo json_encode($response, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: Скажите, вы правда не понимаете, что нелепая фантазия "разделить строки запятыми" **не имеет ни малейшего отношения к вопросу**?  А если бы нельзя было? Ответ как-то изменился бы?

Comment: В вашем варианте вопроса json_encode вообще не нужен.

Comment: Для кого вы разместили этот вопрос? Если только для себя, то зачем вообще это было делать? Если для других, то к чему это нелепое ограничение про "некий репозиторий"? **У других людей тоже этот "репозиторий"?**  Зачем тогда вообще его упоминать?

Comment: Нужно было отметить, что в данном случае не требуется какое либо дополнительное форматирование/экранирование/фикс или что вы еще собирались делать со строками. Получается два условия, так как строки нужно внедрить в некую структуру, то json_encode будет полезен, а раз экранировать слеши не требуется, то штатный режим будет не кстати. Вырезая середину примера, вы обесцениваете необходимость использовать json_encode вообще.  PS: Хватит оскорблять других участников. С таким стажем вы должны быть примером, и больше других знать о [нормах поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: Я не понимаю, как можно не понимать, что для вопроса не имеет значения, нужно что-то куда-то внедрять или не нужно, пришли ли данные из какого-то "репозитория" строки, или из леса вышли. Для ответа на вопрос это все неважно.  Вопрос "использовать json_encode или не использовать" вообще не имеет никакого отношения к проблеме. У вас вопрос про эту функцию. То есть любые рассуждения на тему использовать или нет, не имеют смысла: вы УЖЕ её используете.

Comment: Единственная причина по которой вы задали этот вопрос - это придумать несколько оправданий использованию данного флага. При том что осмысленным из них является только одно - непроверяемое утверждение про "потребителя". Остальные оправдания не имеют смысла, и несут только вред. Чтобы потешить своё эго, вы вредите людям, рассказывая нелепые байки про " гарантировано валидные строки" и " без использования json_encode".

Comment: Если можно предложить более оптимальный вариант, то именно такой и нужно предлагать, это про "без использования json_encode". По всей видимости, вы готовую строку JSON готовы распарсить или отправить в json_decode(), лишь бы в итоге запихать результат в json_encode() перед отправкой.

Comment: Если уж на то пошло, то `{"version":1,"timestamp":"1695788642","data":["https://stackoverflow.com/","DN12345/2023"]}` ТОЖЕ можно собрать корявыми ручонками, без использования специально предназначенной для этого функции.  И что самое смешное - таки находятся гении, которые это делают. Исходя как раз из ваших нелепых идей про "оптимальный вариант" и "гарантированно валидные строки" :) То есть опять же, рассуждения использовать/не использовать здесь просто ни на что не влияют. Л - логика.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148780/discussion-between--and-).